# Perl match next in input

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl script going through input like so:

```
while ( <INPUT> ) {
    if (condition) {
        # match a string 3 lines down from current line
    }
}
```

How do I skip lines and basically "find the next matching line" in the input?

Comment: this could be what you're after: `next if $_ !=~ /<regex>/ `. This will skip to the next line of the input file if the current line you're on does not match the line or pattern you're looking for. You added the `regex` tag so I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for.  However, I found out I now need to skip a variable number of lines.  Since I am doing this inside of an `if` block and need to continue executing more code in the `if` block after matching with the line I want, I'm not sure `next` will work.  That seems to jump back out to the outside `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read from the same filehandle, and skip to a third line,

```
while ( <INPUT> ) {
    if (condition) {
        # match a string 3 lines down from current line
        <INPUT> for 1..2;
        $_ = <INPUT> // last; # eof?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually maintain state variables for this sort of problem:

```
my $condition_last_met;

while ( <INPUT> ) {
    if (condition) {
        $condition_last_met = $.;
    }
    if (defined($condition_last_met) && $condition_last_met + 3 == $.)
    {
        # search the string in the current line
    }
}
```

This example assumes you never match the condition within 3 lines from the previous match, but that can be dealt with in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually set a flag and maintain a count to get specific line to match string. Clear after match.

```
my $conditon_flag = 0;
my $count = 0;
while (<input>)
{
     if(condition)
     {
          $condition_flag = 1;
          $count++;
     }

     if($condition_flag == 1 && $count == 3)
     {
           #match the string;
           $condition_flag = 0;
           $count = 0;
     }
}
```